# Control the order of elements in a power set

Tags: java

I have this code that generates a power set for a given set of elements. In the example, my elements are 1, 2 and 3. So this generates...

`{1}, {2}, {3}, {1, 2}, {1, 3}, {2, 3}, {1, 2, 3}`

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class test {
    static List<List<Integer>> powerSet;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        powerSet = getPowerSet(new ArrayList<Integer>() {
            {
                add(1);
                add(2);
                add(3);
            }
        });
        for (List<Integer> i : powerSet) {
            for (Integer i2 : i) {
                System.out.print(i2 + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }

    private static List<List<Integer>> getPowerSet(List<Integer> itemList) {
        List<List<Integer>> ps = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>();
        ps.add(new ArrayList<Integer>()); // add the empty set

        // for every item in the original list
        for (Integer i : itemList) {
            List<List<Integer>> newPs = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>();

            for (List<Integer> subset : ps) {
                // copy all of the current powerset's subsets
                newPs.add(subset);

                // plus the subsets appended with the current item
                List<Integer> newSubset = new ArrayList<Integer>(subset);
                newSubset.add(i);
                newPs.add(newSubset);
            }

            // powerset is now powerset of list.subList(0, list.indexOf(item)+1)
            ps = newPs;
        }
        ps.remove(0); // remove the emptyset
        return ps;
    }
}
```

The problem is, my result is not ordered, here is what I am getting.

```
3 
2 
2 3 
1 
1 3 
1 2 
1 2 3
```

I would like to get:

```
1 
2 
3  
1 2
1 3 
2 3 
1 2 3
```

Comment: Define _ordered_. Then explain what you've tried to get that result or what is holding you back.

Comment: Ordered means the priority is given to smallest size of set then to smallest number. What's holding me back is I don't know what is determining the order of the set in the first place.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be an sort. You're just putting them in in that order.

Comment: It's not a sort, its just an ordering based on the size of the set then on the value of the numbers. So are you saying this can't be done? If that's the case I can just delete this question before anyone answers.

Comment: I'm saying that's just how your algorithm works. You can sort them after the fact.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can sort them by using the `Collections.sort` with some logic for sorting it by checking it first its length if it is equal to each other and parsing it to int. But you need to store the List of number first to a string so you can check the length and precision of the integer.

**sample:**

```
Collections.sort(powerSet, new Comparator<List<Integer>>() {

        @Override
        public int compare(List<Integer> o1, List<Integer> o2) {
            StringBuilder temp = new StringBuilder();
            StringBuilder temp2 = new StringBuilder();
            for (Integer i2 : o1) {
                temp.append( i2 );
            }
            for (Integer i2 : o2) {
                temp2.append( i2 );
            }

            if(temp.length() == temp2.length())
                return Integer.parseInt(temp.toString()) - Integer.parseInt(temp2.toString());
            else
                return temp.length() - temp2.length();
        }
    });
```

**result:**

```
1 
2 
3 
1 2 
1 3 
2 3 
1 2 3
```

Comment: That was much easier than trying to change the actual powerSet method. Thanks